# Adding checkbox to all tree nodes

Tags: extjs

Consider this example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#check-tree

Is it possible to show check-box for all leaf nodes without adding checked:true/false to all individual nodes?

Similarly, how can I set the icon of all nodes out of the store?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Try this:

```
tree.getRootNode().cascadeBy(function(node) {
    if(node.isLeaf()) {
        node.set({checked:false});
    }
})
```